# How to count items with if case in Laravel Query

Tags: php, laravel

I have subcategories, each subcategory has to contain images, but some subcategories have no image.

I want to count total number of subcategories which has images.

I have made a function using **helper** to check if subcategory has image or not.

```
$subcategories = App\subcategories::where('categories_id',$category->id)->get();
$totalsubcategories = $subcategories->count();
```

**Output:**
400

But suppose only 250 subcategories have images in each and rest 150 subcategories have no image, how can I count total subcategories if it has image.

I have function to check if single subcategory has image or not.

```
Helper::checkifImage($eachsubcat->id)
```

**$eachsubcat** is single subcategory

Comment: `App\subcategories::where('categories_id',$category->id)->has('image')->count()` should work (assuming you have the image relationship in the subcategories model

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry but **image** table is different which has **subcategory ID** coulmn in it.

Comment: if image is a model too, you can define [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship between them and use @apokryfos propose

Comment: Try always to use DB to do this type of counting, as if you have 10k models, counting them in PHP could timeout or run out of memory...

Comment: @matiaslauriti What do you mean by use DB to Count?

Comment: @AnonymousGirl you are running `$subcategories->count();` but `$subcategories` is already a `collection` instead of a `builder`. So you are going to count using PHP instead of the DB and that is not performant for large set of models, it is going to destroy your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer uses the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries) and does not use the [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) or any relationships.

When I have to write a relatively complex query in Laravel I tend to write it in plain SQL first in my database client and test if it gives me the desired results. For your question this might be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM subcategories
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM image
    WHERE image.subcategorie_id = subcategories.categories_id
)
```

According to the [Query Builder 'Where Exists'](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-exists-clauses) documentation, this would translate to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$subcategoriesWithImagesCount = DB::table('subcategories')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('image')
            ->whereColumn('image.subcategorie_id', 'subcategories.categories_id');
    })
    ->count();
```

I chose a `where exists` because this is well documented, but a subquery `where ... in` would work just as well and translate to `->whereRaw('categories_id IN (SELECT subcategorie_id FROM image)')`.

Comment: You are awesome! ❤️

Comment: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520520/how-to-select-items-if-count-more-than-3-in-laravel-query