# How to select items if count more than 3 in Laravel Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a number of same values in my `Query` column of table `searchkeywords`

I want to select if **count > 3** as well as I want to call searchkeywords other data.

e.g. Apple, Apple, Apple, Banana, Banana, Grapes, Grapes, Grapes, Grapes, Orange...

So, select and show `Apple` and `Grapes` only as they are more than 3 with their ID and other column data. 
I am using this query

**Controller code**:

```
$topsearches = DB::table('searchkeywords')
->selectRaw('query,count(*) as count')
->havingRaw('count(*) > 3')
->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
->paginate(15);
```

**View Code:**

```
@foreach($topsearches as $search)
 {{$search->query}}
@endforeach
```

So, I can only call query column, beside this, `id` and `created` columns are also there when I call using **`{{$search->id}}`**, it throws error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Answer (score 3):

the column which you need should be withing selectRaw, as:

```
  $topsearches = DB::table('searchkeywords')
    ->selectRaw('query,id,created,count(*) as count')
    ->havingRaw('count(*) > 3')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('query')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You query won't return correct data

- You are missing `group by`
- You didn't select the `id` and `created` column

I have fixed your query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdb363/4

```
SELECT * 
FROM searchkeywords
WHERE query IN (
    SELECT query
    FROM searchkeywords
    GROUP BY query
    HAVING count(*) > 3
)
```

Your query will return the total of records in the table.